# Implementing an Asset Lifecycle

Tags: libgdx, assets, kotlin

I'm currently developing a game using Kotlin and LibGDX. But this Question should be Framework/Engine agnostic. Given I have a `Screen` class like this:

```
class MyScreen: Screen {

    private val assetManager = AssetManager()

    private var anyTexture: Texture? = null

    override fun show() {
        assetManager.load("/.../anyTexture.png", Texture.class)
        anyTexture = assetManager.get("/.../anyTexture.png", Texture.class)
    }    

    override fun render(delta: Float) {
        // do rendering
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        assetManager.unload("/.../anyTexture.png", Texture.class)
        anyTexture = null
    }
}
```

Every `Screen` I have manages it's own assets.

How would I achieve the same Lifecyle of my assets without using the nullable Type for every asset in the Screen? My Goal is just load all assets when the screen is loaded and then unload them when the game switches to another `Screen`. Has anybody got an idea for implementing this?